# Delete rows with pyodbc freezes and doesn't delete rows

Tags: python, sql, azure, pyodbc

I am writing a script to remove rows from a SQL Azure database. When I execute this script in `Jupyter` notebook it runs forever and never deletes the rows. Any ideas why this script is not executing?

```
key = input("Enter key to remove\n")  
cnxn = pyodbc.connect(
    'DRIVER='+driver+';SERVER='+server+'; UID='+username+';PWD='+ password)
cursor = cnxn.cursor()
sql = "DELETE FROM Customer where CustomerID like '{key}%'"
process = sql.format(key = key)
cursor.execute(process)
cursor.commit()
```

Comment: How big is the Customer table?  If it's really big, this process could legitimately take a while.

Comment: You explicitly called out "executing this script in Jupyter." Does the same script succeed for you in other environments?

Comment: at what comand does it freeze? Try to put each command in a separate cell

Comment: It is a small table, only contains a few hundred records and the script freezes in all environments.

Comment: It freezes at execute()